# Gmail API search operator "newer_than" does not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api, adonis.js

I'm using `gmail-api-sync` module to access Gmail mails and retrieve all sent from Google Alerts. I'm also trying to retrieve emails newer than 1 or 2 days but it doesn't work. I tried to remove the `from` option and it took too long, indicating it was indeed retrieving e-mails much older than 2 days.

```
const options = {
  query:      'from:googlealerts-noreply@google.com',
  newer_than: '1d'
}

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  gmail.queryMessages(oauth, options, (error, response) => {
     // ...
  }
  // ...
})
```

I fail to see what's the reason and if there are different usages than this.

Comment: Since you are using AdonisJs I recommend you to take a look at `pify` to remove this Promise and the callback of `gmail.queryMessages`.

Comment: Ok, I shall take a look some other time. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The example provided wasn't very clear, and now the owner has updated with a [clearer example](https://github.com/fedecia/gmail-api-sync/blob/9ee381621ca3baff7c909abe944bde4a98e06df3/README.md#full-synchronization-requires-oauth2-authentication-see-below)

`var options = {query: 'from:facebook.com newer_than:2d'};`